What does "point set" topology mean?
Is it an antonym for "function set" topology (topology of function spaces) or "point-free" topology (locale theory)? Or other?

great question -- i think it has to be "other" just by the order in which these things were defined, but i don't know the etymology

It certainly excludes algebraic topology.

It is older than function spaces and locales and comes from the foundations of set theory itself; it is a calque of the German Punktmengen (lit. "point-set") that goes all the way back to Cantor, studying exotic subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ where Fourier series might converge (having a good language for this is why he invented set theory).
Point-set topology then means something like "topology, backed up by Cantor's theory" (Poincaré's discoveries in algebraic topology, for example, were contemporaneous with Cantor, although Poincaré didn't use the language of set theory). I learned that from this nice expository paper:
https://math.bu.edu/people/aki/30.pdf

Very interesting reference. (+1)

Point set topology is a common synonym for General topology. It is classified in MSC as 54-XX: General topology.

The Point-Set Topology wikidot page provides some introductory information.

See this MAA review of A Course in Point Set Topology by John B. Conway to get a first impression of what point set topology is all about.

Another great source of information is Counterexamples in Topology by L.A. Steen and L.A. Seebach. The topological spaces considered there can be found in this Wikipage.


